# Repository pattern with EF6 + DatabaseFirst

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

***Current System:***

I am working on a project which is multi layered as shown below (in order of flow) and I am learning and trying to implement Repo Pattern with UOW on EF Database first.

- Service (Web API)
- Business (C# Class Library)
- Repository (Repo Pattern + UOW)
- ViewModels (Used by my Service for sent to my UI layer)
- Data (Entities)
- Database (SQL Server)

***Repository:***

Generic Repository:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    void Create(TEntity entity);
    IQueryable<TEntity> ReadAll();
    TEntity ReadById();
    IQueryable<TEntity> Filter(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    TEntity ReadSingle(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    TEntity ReadSingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}
```

Repository Implementation:

```
internal class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private bool _isDisposed;

    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    private Entities _entities;

    public RepositoryBase(Entities entities)
    {
        this._entities = entities;
        this._dbSet = _entities.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> ReadAll()
    {
        return _dbSet;
    }

    public TEntity ReadById()
    {
        // Dummy return. Don't worry about returning null will be implemented later.
        return null;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Filter(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity ReadSingle(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.Single(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity ReadSingleOrDefault(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Dispose(bool isManuallyDisposing)
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            if (isManuallyDisposing)
                _tatwaEntities.Dispose();
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~RepositoryBase()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
```

Generic UOW:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<MyEntity> MyEntityRepository { get; }
    //Other EntityRepositories

    void SaveChanges();
}
```

UOW Implementation:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private Entities _entities;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _entities = new entities();
    }

    private IRepository<MyEntity> _myEntityRepository;
    public IRepository<MyEntity> MyEntityRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _myEntityRepository ?? (_myEntityRepository = new RepositoryBase<MyEntity>(_entities));
        }
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_entities != null)
            {
                _entities.Dispose();
                _entities = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Business Logic

```
public List<MyViewModel> ReadMyViewModelList()
    {
        var myVMList = new List<MyViewModel>();
        using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            userList.AddRange(unitOfWork.MyEntityRepository.ReadAll().Select(myEntity => new myViewModel
            {
                Prop1 = myEntity.Prop1,
                Prop1 = myEntity.Prop2,
        etc...
            }));
        }

        return myVMList;
    }
```

***Problem:***

- My problem now is that, in my business code, when i use UOW to get
  data, I have to cast MyEntity to MyViewModel which I think is wrong.
  because the whole idea of using Repo Pattern with UOW is to abstract
  and avoid DB/Entity dependency on the business code and be able to
  independently test that layer.
- I am creating an instance of my DBEntities in both ReposirotyBase and
  UOW implemntation classes, which again I think is wrong and should
  only be created once and I am not sure where is the best place and
  way yo create that instance.
- Is my architecture model the correct approach? If not can someone
  please suggest the appropriate changes to it so as to make it more
  testable, maintainable and sound.

Hope my question is elaborate. As I am in my learning phase of laying down architecture, I appreciate any additional suggestions/comments/improvements.

Cheers.

Comment: Repository is an abstraction on storage, EF is an abstraction on Relational Databases. do you really need an abstraction on storage? unneeded layers of abstraction is unneeded complexity is not good
Also Generic Repositories are seen by many developers as an anti-pattern, for example http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I design my repositories, hope it helps. The contract looks like :

```
public interface IFooRepository
{
  void Add(Foo foo);
  IReadonlyList<Foo> GetAll();
  IReadonlyList<Foo> GetAParticularSubset();
  Foo GetById(int id);
  Foo Remove(int id);
}
```

- Notice the collection semantics. The repository is designed as if it were an in-memory list of domain objects you can add to, remove or query from. *The primary role of a Repository is to act as an abstraction for us to pretend that the database never existed*. So no `Update()`, no `Commit()` or such. Methods return simple readonly lists of objects, no `IQueryable` because it would be a [leaky abstraction](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/) from your lower persistence layer with unneeded features such as advanced query manipulation.
- Internally, concrete EF repositories have a `DbContext`. They use it to add/remove stuff and query, but not to save changes (see below).
- Unit of Work has a dumb simple signature :

  public interface IUnitOfWork
   {
    void SaveChanges();
   }

  This is the "I commit my business transaction, please flush it to whatever all this has to be stored into" part that's missing from the Repository. We basically don't want it to be in the repo because Separation of Concerns. Providing people with a bunch of objects and providing a context which keeps track of changes in these objects in relation with a persistent store are two very different things.

  The tricky thing is, as it turns out, Entity Framework can and will do both under the covers for you. Both features are embodied in a `DbContext`. But while Repository will call `DbContext.Foos.Add/Remove`/query methods, UnitOfWork will only call `DbContext.SaveChanges()`.
- Consequently, both `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` will need to have a reference to a `DbContext`. It has to be the same instance of DbContext if you want changes in the objects to take effect. This can be done by injecting the same instance into both via your DI Container (assuming you're using one).
- From a consumer standpoint, *you only need to place yourself in a `UnitOfWork` scope when you intend to change the objects*. For simple querying where the results won't be modified, just use a Repo.

Comment: +1 for Awesome and simple explanation. Now From my question out of 3 I got two answers. However, is it still valid to use Entities in the Business layer?

Comment: You should *exclusively* use business entities returned by repositories in your business layer. ViewModels should be built in a layer that has some knowledge of the View. Mapping business objects to ViewModels is a distinct, non-business concern.

Comment: I am mapping my Entities with viewmodels in business layer and return view model to my service and eventually to my View/UI/html. I gues this approach is fine?

Comment: @guillaume31 `The primary role of a Repository is to act as an abstraction for us to pretend that the database never existed`. I disagree, its role is to abstract persistence **details**. The collection metaphor is not a law, it's just an example. _Update_ is fine because we know we're dealing with persistence,but we don't know **which** persistence. A repository might be implemented as a real collection, but not every repository _must_ behave like a real one.

Comment: @Immortal In a complex and maintainable app, the UoW is basically a process (short or long lived) and it's implemented as a business process. From a technical point of view, a db transaction is a UoW and a repo should  make sure the whole object is properly saved. But the repo doesn't care about a high level UoW(the process) or other repos. As far as it's concerned the UoW inside the repo is the db transaction or the ORM's SaveChanges. Repo/UoW is [often misused](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2014/06/04/Unit-Of-Work-is-the-new-Singleton.aspx) and this leads to hard to maintain apps

Comment: @MikeSW can you point me to an example for me understand better, so as to avoid common mistakes and make my architecture sound and solid.

Comment: @MikeSW It's not only my view, it's also Eric Evan's -- see "Domain Driven Design" p. 151. Seeing the Repository as a collection is not mentioned as just an example there but as its very definition (printed in bold). He's also perfectly explicit about what methods should be exposed by a Repo. This suits me well not because this is Eric Evans but because it satisfies separation of concerns. Note that I'm totally OK with your take on it though, I wouldn't actually call it a big difference.

Comment: @Immortal I wouldn't call that a fine approach, since your business layer would be tightly coupled to the Web layer, and I suppose vice versa if you want the services to call into the domain, so there'd be a circular reference problem (unless using dependency inversion via abstractions, but in which layer would those be defined ?) Usually the business (or Domain) layer isn't tightly coupled to anything and it doesn't map its own objects to View models because it's not its responsibility. That would mean cracking your business layer open each time you want to present stuff differently in the UI

Comment: All my entities and view models are in a separate project which is referenced in Repository, Business and so forth. How can I avoid this and separate out my unnecessary dependency?

Comment: @guillaume31 how and where can I implement paging and sorting in this architecture, obviously I am passing the sort source, pageIndex, pageSize from UI.